# Connect to mLab

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mlab

I tried connecting to mLab using Python but I'm still having trouble with connection.

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
class TensorDB(object):
"""
def __init__(self, ip = 'ds125058.mlab.com', port = 25058, db_name = 'mkdnb', user_name = 'manal',password = '******', ... ):

 client = MongoClient(ip, port)
  self.db = client[db_name]
  self.db.authenticate(user_name, password)
```

and still there's no connection established

Comment: Do you get any specific error message?

Comment: You typed all this in, via command line? Looks like indentation could be a problem, as your code doesn't properly formatted at all...

Comment: no error , it looks like it's loading something but still no response !

Comment: Also: You'll want to change your credentials immediately. You've published everything, including username and password. Run, don't walk, to the mLab  portal and change your password. Probably a good idea to delete your database user and create a new one, too.

Comment: It's not actually my username and password , I put it as an example !

Answer (score 0):

Visit **https://mlab.com/databases/mkdnb#users** (**Note that** *you must be logged in for this shortcut to work*.)

Ensure that in the Users tab there is a user named `manal`. If you don't know the password for this user, recreate the user.

```
connection_params = {
    'user': 'manal',
    'password': '****',
    'host': 'ds125058.mlab.com',
    'port': 25058,
    'namespace': 'mkdnb',
}

connection = MongoClient(
    'mongodb://{user}:{password}@{host}:'
    '{port}/{namespace}'.format(**connection_params)
)

db = connection.mkdnb

print(db.collection_names())
```